# How can I obtain a sketch or hand-drawn look in Silverlight for various controls?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, pixel-shader

I am looking to create a Silverlight application that employs a control style similar to what one might see when using [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) or [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx).

I am not sure how this look is best achieved in Silverlight.  My initial thought is that clever use of a pixel shader effect on the desired control might just do the trick, however, my searches for a similar solution have failed.

What might be the best approach for drawing controls with a hand-drawn look in Silverlight?

Can this be done with a custom pixel shader?

*Note: I am using Silverlight 3, but would not be opposed to using Silverlight 4 Beta if it provided a more elegant solution to the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

[This guy](http://blog.nerdplusart.com/archives/handdrawnshapes) has a `HandDrawnBorder` style in the source he provides on his website. An example of using his styles is [shown here](http://community.softwarefx.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2009/07/11/displaying-charts-in-a-blend-3-sketchflow-prototype.aspx). It does say that this is for the Beta2 of WPF but that the source should compile and be usable in later releases.

**EDIT:** Looks like the download is broken. Might have to do some hunting...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UX Musings Rough theme](http://blogs.msdn.com/corrinab/archive/2008/08/04/8828013.aspx).

There's also a nice set of [sketch style icons](http://www.iconfinder.net/search/?q=iconset%3A49handdrawing) I found on Icon Finder.